# How to apply custom (proprietary) font for paragraph in python docx?

Tags: python-docx

I am a bit lost with reading the python docx documentation.

I read the file with a proprietary font inside.

```
document_original = docx.Document('doc_orig.docx')
styles = document_original.styles
propitiatory_default = styles['Default']
```

I check that indeed the style has the font I need.

```
print(proprietary_default.font.name)
```

I create a new document with text with the style and font I need.

```
doc = docx.Document()
para = doc.add_paragraph()
para.style = proprietary_default
para_run = para.add_run('this is a text')
file_new = 'font_test_2'
doc.save(  file_new+ '.docx')
```

However if I open the file, I do not see the proprietary_default style.

```
document_new = docx.Document(file_new+'.docx')
styles = document_new.styles
for s in styles:
    print(s.name)
```

Do you know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: As far as I know docx file is a container, where one can find references to the fonts used, no? But I never tried it, nor python-docx

Comment: Yep, but I do know where to find the proprietary font in xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font should be applied not to style, but to paragraphs' font name:

```
doc = docx.Document()
para = doc.add_paragraph()
para_run = para.add_run('this is a text')
para_run.font.name=proprietary_default.font.name
```